# Astyanax parepared statement withvalues() not working properly

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

today I migrated to Astyanax 1.56.42 and discovered, that withValues() on prepared statements doesn't seem to work properly with **SQL SELECT...WHERE...IN ()**.

```
ArrayList<ByteBuffer> uids = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>(fileUids.size());
for (int i = 0; i < fileUids.size(); i++) {
    uids.add(ByteBuffer.wrap(UUIDtoByteArray(fileUids.get(i)), 0, 16));
}

result = KEYSPACE.prepareQuery(CF_FILESYSTEM)
    .withCql("SELECT * from files where file_uid in (?);")
    .asPreparedStatement()
    .withValues(uids)
    .execute();
```

If my ArrayList contains more than one entry, this results in error

```
SEVERE: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.BadRequestException: BadRequestException: [host=hostname(hostname):9160, latency=5(5), attempts=1]InvalidRequestException(why:there were 1 markers(?) in CQL but 2 bound variables)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to handle a **SQL SELECT...WHERE...IN ()** - statement or did I find a bug?

Best regards
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned because you are supplying a collection (ArrayList) to a single `?` Astyanax throws an exception. I think you need to add a `?` for each element you want to have inside the `IN` clause.

Say you want to have 2 ints stored in an ArrayList called arrayListObj the where clause, your statement looks like this:

```
SELECT & FROM users WHERE somevalue IN (arrayListObj);
```

Because you are suppling a collection, this cant work, so you will need multiple `?`'s. I.e. you want :

```
SELECT name, occupation FROM users WHERE userid IN (arrayListObj.get(0), arrayListObj.get(1));
```

I couldn't find anything on the [Astyanax wiki](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Cql-and-cql3#prepared-cql) about using the `IN` clause with prepared statements.

Comment: I did exactly this workaround. But I see this as a workaround. Maybe Netflix canged it's behavior recently as stated in https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/pull/360. I'll try it out as soon as the new version is out.